# Setting fill color for UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have the following `UIImage()`

```
+ (UIImage *)defaultImage {
    static UIImage *defaultImage = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20.f, 13.f), NO, 0.0f);

        [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 1)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 5, 20, 1)] fill];

        [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 1)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 1, 20, 2)] fill];

        [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 6,  20, 2)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 11, 20, 2)] fill];

        defaultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    });

    return defaultImage;
}
```

I'm using it here:

```
buttonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[self class] defaultImage] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleLeftPanel:)];
```

The problem is that the `setFill` colours aren't working. The rectangles are always red.

They're actually taking on the colour of the `navigationBar.tintColor` of the `UIViewController`.

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`

If I remove the `tintColor` then they're always blue.

Comment: Hi @gotnull, I don't have the answer, just an FYI, there is a tool called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) which outputs code for graphics that you draw. I often use this to see how CoreGraphics does things. There is a trial that you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the following:

```
buttonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[[self class] defaultImage] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleLeftPanel:)];
```

What's happening is that the image is being rendered as a "template", that is, only the alpha channel is being drawn with the colour coming from the `navigationBar`'s `tintColor`.